# Can i choose more then one value for an attribute in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am experimenting with ManipulationMode in XAML for an Windows store app. I want to have as many settings directly in my xaml so I don't have to use the code behind so much. When I found a solution to get my swipe recognition working I found something to do in code behind like the following:

```
myGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
```

Now I tried to get this working by using some xaml code. I then used this

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" ManipulationMode="TranslateY" ManipulationCompleted="manipulationCompleted">
```

This works fine but I didn't find a way to use ManipulationMode TranslateX AND TranslateY at the same time.

I tried to add some boolean operators in the attribute and the following snippet inside my grid.

```
<Grid.ManipulationMode>
   <ManipulationModes>TranslateX</ManipulationModes>
   <ManipulationModes>TranslateY</ManipulationModes>
</Grid.ManipulationMode>
```

What do I get wrong or is it not possible to make this in pure XAML?

Thanks Hermann

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use comma separated values.

Comment: That solution was way to simple to figure out >.<